# Keep only lines that end with "@here" (RegEx, Python)

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file with almost a thousand lines such as:

> WorldNews,Current 
>   WorldNews,Current,WorldNews@here',
>   'WorldNewsPro@here Zebra,Poacher',
>   'Dock,DS_URLs@here'
>   Zebra,Poacher,ZebraPoacher@here
>   Zebra,Dock,ZebraDock@here
>   Timer33,Timer33@here

Sometimes the line ends without "@here" sometimes it ends with "@here" sometimes it has "@here" in the middle of the line and sometimes the line ends with "@here'"

I want to strip all the lines that do NOT have "@here" in them at all. I tried RegEx:

```
> (^(@here$))  
> [\W](@here)
```

etc. with no luck.

How should I pull the lines with "@here" so my new file (or the output) has only:

> WorldNews,Current,WorldNews@here',
>   'WorldNewsProfessional52@here
>   Zebra,Poacher',
>   'DocuShare,AC_DS_URLs@here'
>   Zebra,Poacher,ZebraPoacher@here
>   Zebra,DocuShare,ZebraDocushare@here
>   XNTimer,XNTimer@here

I was thinking it should read the whole line from start to end and if it has @here anywhere in the line, print it. If not, ignore and read the next line.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this helps: (assuming `filename` is the name of your input file)

```
with open(filename) as stream:
    for line in stream:
        if '@here' in line:
            print line
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need regex. You can use a string methods to do such simple filtering:

```
def hasstr( lines, s ):
    # a generator expression can filter out the lines
    return (line for line in lines if s in line)

# get all lines in the file with @here in them     
filtered = hasstr(open(the_file, 'rt'), '@here')
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the `in` operator.

```
for line in sys.stdin:
  if '@here' in line:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```